# How to react on click from the line in list?

Tags: php, html

Someone can help me to solve this
I have this html select tag, and I have a button,
how to react on the one line from this list and press the button, so this line will be redirected to another page?

```
<p><strong>Select your favorite species of flamingo.</strong></p>

<select size="6">
          <option value="American">American flamingo</option>
          <option value="Andean">Andean flamingo</option>
          <option value="Chilean">Chilean flamingo</option>
          <option value="Greater">Greater flamingo</option>
          <option value="James's">James's flamingo</option>
          <option value="Lesser">Lesser flamingo</option>
</select>
```

```
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" OK!">
```

Comment: Do you need the server(PHP) for this? I guess all you need is JavaScript to change the document *location* when the user selects something from the list.

Comment: no, i need with php, I even don't know to to ask google to have examples like this.. I hope you understand the question :)

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you want to achieve, I think you want the user to navigate to another page when he changes the selected item from the list, is that correct ?

Comment: Well let's say, I have few other pages with pictures of these flamingos, depending on what flamingo I will click from the list and then I will click OK, it will redirect to a page with picture with this flamingo. So yes, you are right, I just don't know how to store for example first flamingo in the button

Comment: *"I just don't know how to store for example first flamingo in the button"* ... you don't store the links to the flamingo's pictures in the button, you store them in the `value` attribute of the `<option value="/url/to/american/flamingo/picture">American flamingo</option>` tag or in data-*  attributes like `<option data-url="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this if you have some php in place. It's standard form controls functionality. I'm assuming you have some kind of script reading some parameter. I'm going to call the script `photos.php` and the parameter `species`.

```
<form method="get" action="photos.php">
  <select name="species">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="American">American flamingo</option>
    <option value="Andean">Andean flamingo</option>
    <option value="Chilean">Chilean flamingo</option>
    <option value="Greater">Greater flamingo</option>
    <option value="James's">James's flamingo</option>
    <option value="Lesser">Lesser flamingo</option>
  </select>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" OK!">
</form>
```

Then, in your php, check the value and redirect:

```
if (isset($_GET['species'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['species'], ['American', 'Andean'])) { // Other species omitted
      header('Location: /photos/'. $_GET['species'] . '.html';
      exit();
    }
} else {
     // Output your selection form
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need. Thx

Answer (score 1):

**If I don't misunderstood your question** then you can do this way using JS, Also you can do this with simple `.php` form submit on a particular page and then check which option value is selected. Finally redirect to a flower page based on the selected option value as @msg pointed.

`window.location.replace` will redirect you to the page as per your selection.

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    let selected_option =  document.getElementById('option').value;
    window.location.replace(selected_option);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <p><strong>Select your favorite species of flamingo.</strong></p>

  <select id="option" size="6" name="flamigos">
    <option value="American.html">American flamingo</option>
    <option value="Andean.html">Andean flamingo</option>
    <option value="Chilean.html">Chilean flamingo</option>
    <option value="Greater.html">Greater flamingo</option>
    <option value="James's.html">James's flamingo</option>
    <option value="Lesser.html">Lesser flamingo</option>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" OK!">
</form>
```

Comment: Where I type my redirected page?

Comment: do you have pages like `American.html`, `Andean.html` and so on that you added as select options?